# Total War:Warhammer, what unlocks can you gain from campaign

Tags: warhammer-total-war

Last night I finished the wood elves story campaign. When I did I unlocked "Mousillon: The Red duke" for Singleplayer and Multiplayer. Now I was wondering if this was the only faction or are there more unlockable characters/factions that I can get. A list of these and how to get them would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlockable units and factions
Boris Todbringer (The Empire and Middeland)
-Type of unit: sir: infantry with sword.
-Requirements: Have Total War: WARHAMMER - Call of the Beastmen and complete the Eye for an Eye campaign.

Middeland
-Requirements: Have Total War: WARHAMMER - Call of the Beastmen and complete the Eye for an Eye campaign.

Mousillon
-Requirements: have Total War: WARHAMMER - Realm of the Wood Elves and complete the campaign The Epoch of Revelation.

Sarthorael the Eternal Watcher (Warriors of Chaos)
-Type of unit: sir: wizard.
-Requirements: complete the Great Campaign campaign with any faction.

The Red Duke (Vampire Counts and Mousillon)
-Type of unit: sir: infantry with sword.
-Requirements: have Total War: WARHAMMER - Realm of the Wood Elves and complete the campaign The Epoch of Revelation.
Unlockable dlc's
30 Regiments of Renown
-Type of dlc: new units to Beastmen, Wood Elves, Chaos Warriors, Bretonnia and Norsca.
-Requirements: Be registered in Total War ACCESS[dashboard.totalwar.com].
Credit: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=735822875
Here is a list of unlockable factions

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere. Make sure you give credit to where you got this from. We frown on plagiarization rather heavily.

Comment: I did give credit, it was https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=735822875.  Sorry my bad, I meant to add it

Comment: Its a good idea to edit that into your answer.

Comment: I just added it!

Comment: You added it as a comment; you need to edit your answer to include it. Stuff is comments is transient; we don't expect it to stick around.